# Easiest way to create server for storing list of highscores for javascript game?

Tags: javascript, database, arrays, webserver

Alright, so I'm doing a school project where I have to implement Space Invaders with JavaScript. It's basically done but the teacher wants that there's a score list. I just want a server where I can post player's score with jQuery and fetch existing scores from the server after the game has ended. Basically I was thinking to implement it like this (may not be the wisest solution):

1. Player plays the game
2. Game is over -> fetch all scores from the server as an array
3. Add current score to the array
4. Sort array into descending order
5. Splice array so that there will be only 5 best scores
6. Show score list to player
7. Post current score to the server
8. Repeat

So any suggestions how to create this kind of a simple server (post scores & get scores)? I'm not really familiar with this stuff.

Comment: Are there any server side technologies you are either comfortable with or are interseted in learning? Django (Python), Ruby on Rails, ASP.NET MVC, NodeJS, etc etc

Comment: It really depends on which language you are used to work with. PHP will be really fast to make that kind of work, with a bit of PDO for the database. But you cana also do it with Python (Flask, Django, Tornado), Java (Play), RoR, etc etc. And if you don't have to track score between multiple users, you can store the scores in the Local Storage (HTML5)

Comment: I'd be inclined to say node.js (since you apparently already know some JavaScript) with either a text file (in JSON format) or CSV to save and retrieve scores. It's as simple system, don't over-engineer it with a full-on database.

Comment: Matt: I'm not familiar with either one of those.

Cyril N: At first I used local storage, but for some reason my teacher didn't like it.

BLSully: I guess NodeJS could be the way to go, maybe. It's time to google a bit, I've heard about CSV but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @KennyRoberts: CSV just means "comma separated values" (or sometimes tab-delimited). It's an easy way to store small amounts of data and easily parsed without resorting to more complicated file (or data) formats. serializing an array of `PlayerScore` objects to JSON and writing to a file is likely a slightly easier option though due to the built in `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` methods in JavaScript

Comment: I think node.js in combination with [socket.io](http://socket.io/) has one advantage that is not in your list of requirements: you can easily create a live highscore table which updates the list in real time, without the user needing to actively refresh the page. But this might be out of scope of your school project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems [this tutorial](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide) on Parse was created just for you! (The example is even a high scores example.)

Parse is a persistence library that allows you to get by without writing any server code.

Comment: Pretty cool service. Hadn't run across that one before. Would be a perfect solution for the OP

Comment: Wow, this was amazing! Easy to use and just what I needed. Thanks! Also thanks for other people's suggestions!

Comment: One more question if anyone is watching this: how can I make scores user-specific? I'd like to do it so that user doesn't have to fill out any forms (username for example). I tried to google how to get IP address in JavaScript but yeah, you can't.

Comment: You could use cookies to achieve something like this. Basically generate a random ID when the user visits the page for the first time and store it via cookie (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and save it to the server with the high scores... Then only list the high scores associated with that ID at the end of the game.

Comment: Alright, works like a charm now! Thanks again :)

Comment: I think Parse is shutting down :(:(

Answer (score 2):

If you already know client side JS-development, you could look at [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) (server-side JavaScript environment) and store the results in a CSV or a textfile.

Another option is to use the [Google Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample) for Javascript to store/fetch the game results.